# Spring Boot console logs not coming

Tags: spring-boot

I am using spring boot and in the logs (console), nothing is coming up except for spring boot ascii art logo. I have slf4j in the classpath pulled by a dependency.

Comment: Can you post your build configuration file?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `spring-boot-starter-logging` to your POM file instead of `slf4j`.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue, when I putted the logs config in external configuration file, then I used it that way:

```
@PropertySource(value = {"file:${EXTERNAL_PROPERTIES_FILE}"})
```

Now It's working after moving the log configuration to application.properties in src/main/resources/